# If V is a non-zero completely reducible module, it contains an irreducible submodule

Tags: modules

I'm trying to understand a proof of this from my textbook. It starts by saying that we can assume V is finitely generated, but I'm not sure why we can make that assumption. Is there something that goes wrong in the infinitely generated case?

Other than that the proof is straightforward. I appreciate your insight!

Comment: Sorry ,but what is the ring associated to the module?

Comment: What's your definition of *completely reducible*?

Comment: @Tommasco Scognamiglio, it's an arbitrary module with an arbitrary ring

Comment: @egreg completely reducible in this case means that any submodule W of V is a summand of V. W is a summand of V if there is a submodule C such that W + C = V and the intersection of W and C is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer. It occurred to me that I can choose a finite number of vectors in my module and generate a submodule out of them. The proof then reduces to the finitely generated case, which I can understand no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The key fact is that any submodule of a completely reducible module is completely reducible.  So if $M$ is a nonzero completely reducible module, you can pick any nonzero element $m\in M$ and consider the submodule $N$ generated by $m$.  It then suffices to find an irreducible module of this nonzero module $N$, which is finitely generated.  In fact, this shows you can assume your module is not just finitely generated but cyclic.

Comment: Looks like an extra "ir-" snuck into the last "completely reducible" in the first sentence.